# PMwiki doesn't work anymore after upgrade to CentOS7

Tags: centos7, pmwiki

We had PMwiki installed in a few directories under public_html running on our old CentOS6 server.

The home directories were on a file system (RAID) separate from the system, so they were not affected by the installation of CentOS7 from scratch.

Now the 'normal' pages under public_html are accessible, php works (version 7 instead of 5), mysql works, but when i point the browser to one of the pmwiki-pages nothing is displayed, not even an error message.

On another post from here i read that to port pmwiki from one  server to another one it is sufficient to copy the wiki.d directory. But in this case i didn't even touch the pmwiki.

Is there a way to get the system going again, or at least to find out what the problem is?

edit:

To clarify:

```
http://newserver/~QHG/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/QHG2/QHG2
```

does **not** work, but

```
http://newserver/~QHG/pmwiki/test.html
```

**does** work

Comment: Maybe Selinux? Firewall? Check locally if it works, eg. `curl http://localhost`

Comment: Usually apache returns an error message if it can't access a page. But in this case no error is displayed, just a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is around .htaccess config and your [Clean URLs](https://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/CleanUrls) config.

You can download and install fresh PmWiki package and see if it works from the box. If it works, compare .htaccess and /local/config.php files from both installs to find out what is wrong.